# mail function not working for personal domain

Tags: php, email

I'm using php mail function to send email in my project. Emails are coming on gmail,yahoo and other public email services but these are not coming on private domain email ids like info@mydomain.com . Please help me.
My code is:

```
$to = 'email@mydomain.com';
$subject = "Subject line of email";
$body = "Body of email";
$header = "From: MYDOMAIN <no-reply@mydomain.com>" . "\r\n";
$header .= "\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$body,$header);
```

Comment: This is not work on localhost

Comment: did you check the junk folder?

Comment: its possible in server only noti n localhost

Comment: I have checked junk folder and this is also not running on localhost.

Comment: If you send a email from gmail to your "info@mydomain.com", the email coming into account?

Comment: @Mate I checked it, email not coming from gmail to info@mydomain.com but it's comimg from abc@mydomain.com

Comment: Ok, I believe the code is correct. The problem is that your account is not accepting emails from another domain, just from xxx@mydomain.com. Check config for your  xxx@mydomain.com. emails accounts... Maybe accepting emails... but the server is slow ... or something is down inside them.